# Image processing issues with blood vessels

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to extract the blood vessels from an image, and to do so, I'm first equalizing the image, applying CLAHE histogram to obtain the following result:

```
        clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=100.0, tileGridSize=(100,100))
        self.cl1 = clahe.apply(self.result_array)
        self.cl1 = 255 - self.cl1
```

[image]

And then I'm using OTSU threshold to extract the blood vessels, but failing to do it well:

```
self.ret, self.thresh = cv2.threshold(self.cl1, 0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.float32)/1
        self.thresh = cv2.erode(self.thresh, kernel, iterations=3)
        self.thresh = cv2.dilate(self.thresh, kernel, iterations=3)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Obviously there's a lot of noise. I've tried using Median blur, but it just clusters the noise and makes it into a blob, in some places. How do I go about removing the noise to get the blood vessels?

This is the original image from which I'm trying to extract the blood vessels:

[image]

Comment: Please attach an original image and expected output.

Comment: I don't have the desired output, sorry.  I've attached the original.

Comment: Would you try setting tileGridSize=(8,8) to something more like (20,20)? I believe euqlizing is a bit too aggressive. It wouldn't entirely solve the problem, but might lead to better results.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried that, and you're right, it does improve the result, but nothing of much significance.

Comment: Oh well. I am not familiar with OpenCV, I could just explain how I would try solving it. Step 1: creating a map of noise level around each pixel. Step 2: calculating median noise. Step 3: for each pixel multiply lightness of the original image by noise level (from the map step 1) minus median+threshold.

Comment: can you add the original image with a lossless compression instead (e.g. save as .png instead of .jpg)? Or do you work on jpeg images?

Comment: I work on JPEG images.  Would you like me to upload the png?  I'll do it as soon as I get to the computer.

Comment: A png would help, since part of the noise might be coming from compression. Have you tried any segmentation algorithms? E.g. some of those: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html

Comment: @Micka , just made the edit and attached the png.

Comment: @GrisgorisG  just made the edit and attached the png

Comment: The original is still a JPEG...

Comment: Am I missing something, or the erode/dilate part of your code actually has no effect?

Comment: You could use a NN for this, just train a pixel classifier with labeled data that is already publicly available. See this [method](https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/760800.clanak_review.pdf). This might be an [idea](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf) also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Getting really good results is a difficult problem (you'll probably have to somehow model the structure of the blood vessels and the noise) but you can probably still do better than filtering.

One technique for addressing this kind of problems, inspired by the Canny edge detector, is using two thresholds - `[hi,low]` and classifying a pixel `p` with response `r` as belonging to a blood vessel `V` if `r > hi` || (`r > lo` && one of `p`'s neighbors is in `V`).

Also, when it comes to filtering, both bilateral filtering and meanshift filtering are good for noisy images.

```
kernel3 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
kernel5 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
kernel7 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(7,7))
t_lo = 136
t_hi = 224

blured = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(img, 3, 9)
#blured = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 9, 32, 72)

clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=128.0, tileGridSize=(64, 64))
cl1 = clahe.apply(blured)
cl1 = 255 - cl1

ret, thresh_hi = cv2.threshold(cl1, t_hi, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
ret, thresh_lo = cv2.threshold(cl1, t_lo, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
```

[image: low threshold]
Low threshold image
[image: hi threshold]
Hi threshold image

Preparations and cleanup:

```
current = np.copy(thresh_hi)
prev = np.copy(current)
prev[:] = 0
current = cv2.morphologyEx(current, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel5)
iter_num = 0
max_iter = 1000
```

Not the most efficient way to do that... but easy to implement:

```
while np.sum(current - prev) > 0 and iter_num < max_iter:
    iter_num = iter_num+1
    prev = np.copy(current)
    current = cv2.dilate(current, kernel3)
    current[np.where(thresh_lo == 0)] = 0
```

[image: initial mask]
Initial mask

Remove small blobs:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(current, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area < 256:
        cv2.drawContours( current, [contour], 0, [0,0,0], -1 )
```

[image: refined mask]
After removing small blobs

Morphological cleanup:

```
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(current, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel7)   
cl1[np.where(opening == 0)] = 0
```

[image: result]
Result

This is by no means optimal, but I think it should provide you with enough tools to start.

Answer (score 6):

How about:
High-Pass (image minus Gaussian smooth with sigma 12), then threshold (126) and then small-objects suppression (objects that are smaller than 300 pixels are removed) ?

(I worked with your last image)

[image]

[image]

[image]